# Pod cannot be allocated with FailedScheduling error

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to run a pod with relatively small limits on a cluster with 3 nodes and it gives me the following error when I run a `describe` on the pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  18s (x2 over 18s)  default-scheduler  0/6 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory, 3 PodToleratesNodeTaints, 4 NoVolumeZoneConflict.
```

In the meantime when I check the nodes it all seems fine:

```
NAME                                          CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
ip-172-20-101-66.eu-west-1.compute.internal   113m         2%        3353Mi          21%       
ip-172-20-39-218.eu-west-1.compute.internal   364m         9%        7054Mi          44%       
ip-172-20-60-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal   109m         2%        3162Mi          19%       
ip-172-20-66-24.eu-west-1.compute.internal    183m         4%        3570Mi          22%       
ip-172-20-76-91.eu-west-1.compute.internal    332m         8%        5011Mi          31%       
ip-172-20-98-243.eu-west-1.compute.internal   579m         14%       6889Mi          43%
```

The following is the limits on the pod:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 50m
    memory: 0.5Gi
  requests:
    cpu: 50m
    memory: 0.5Gi
```

I can't seem to find any indication that there's limits on nodes, so I'm kind of lost. Can someone please suggest why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The event message appears to describe only one of the nodes has insufficient memory. It also calls attention to Node Taints and Volume Zones.

Perhaps it's worth trying to submit a simpler Pod Spec with the same resources, but with no volumes attached. This won't resolve your issue but may help you in isolating it further.